# ploting Gamma(Z) with maple

Tags: plot, complex-numbers, maple

How do one plot the absolute value of the $|\Gamma(z)|$ with Maple?
As in the WIKI figure:
http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gammafunktion#mediaviewer/File:Gamma_abs_3D.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command [plots:-complexplot3d](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=plots/complexplot3d) is intended as a convenient way of obtaining such plots (using z instead of the [plot3d](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=plot3d) command with x+I*y, and putting in the labels automatically).

```
P := plots:-complexplot3d( abs(GAMMA(z)), z=-4-4*I..4+4*I,
                           view=[-4..4,-4..4,0..6], orientation=[-120,75] ):
```

For some reason, the surface stored in structure P gets some blue color that overrides the shading scheme.

```
P;
```

[image]

If we remove that COLOR substructure then the underlying shading scheme (which we could change in the original call, using the [shading](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=plot3d/option) option) is revealed.

```
subsindets(P,specfunc(anything,COLOR),u->NULL);
```

[image]

I will submit a bug report about that heavy-handed blue coloring.

Answer (score 1):

```
plot3d(
     abs(GAMMA(x+I*y)), x= -4.6..5.1, y= -5.1..5.1, 
     view= [DEFAULT$2, 0..6], 
     labels= [Re(z), Im(z), ``], title = abs(GAMMA(z)) 
);
```